# WARNING: Argument 2 to function PUTC referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range

Tags: sas, proc-format

I am trying to use the product of a Proc Format statement as the format in a %sysfunc statement as so:

```
proc format;
value myvar
1 = "One" 2 = "Two" 3 = "Three" 4 = "Four";
run;

%let i = 1;

%let dvar = %sysfunc(putc(&i, $myvar.));
%put &dvar;
```

However I keep getting the error in the title of the post:

```
WARNING: Argument 2 to function PUTC referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range.
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Thanks

Comment: The value you're formatting is numeric, have you tried `PUTN` instead?

Comment: Also, `myvar.` should be referenced as such, without the `$`

Comment: @mjsqu hi, thanks for replying. '%let dvar = %sysfunc(putn(&i, myvar.));
' did what I needed.

Comment: @mjsqu You should put your response in an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in the end:

```
proc format;
value myvar
1 = "One" 2 = "Two" 3 = "Three" 4 = "Four";
run;

%let i = 1;

%let dvar = %sysfunc(putn(&i, myvar.));
%put &dvar;
```

Thanks